# change order of properties in object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Have an array with objects like this:

```
    [{id: "58eeed338b115",  name: "Bob", avatar: "" },
{id: "58eeed338b115",  name: "Bob", avatar: "" }]
```

I need change order of properties to this:

```
    [{avatar: "",  name: "Bob",id: "58eeed338b115"},
{avatar: "",  name: "Bob",id: "58eeed338b115"} ]
```

in real task I have about 20 obj, how to change order? use for in? I have no ideas how to do this. I want setup manualy order, params in obj can be about 10

Comment: Properties aren't ordered in an object. Why do you need this?

Comment: @chazsolo they are by insertion order... except when they are numbers.

Comment: @DanielA.White True. However, if I'm assuming correctly, OP isn't manually inserting them in a specific order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [{id: "58eeed338b115",  name: "Bob", avatar: "" },
{id: "58eeed338b115",  name: "Bob", avatar: "" }]

const sortOrder = {'avatar': 1, 'id': 2, 'name': 3}



const res = arr.map(o => Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(o).sort((a, b) => sortOrder[a] - sortOrder[b]).map(x => { return { [x]: o[x]}})))

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
```

Comment: I don;t need reverse, I need setup order manually

Comment: What do you mean? Be more specific.

Comment: for exampe I want setup : ID, AVATAR, NAME or ID, NAME,AVATR, not make reverse

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко but... the order you specified is the reverse of the original order. so... reverse puts it in the order you specified. Either way, this answer shows that you can re-order the properties, you should be able to take this answer and apply your own order by replacing .reverse with what would put them in the order you want.

Comment: no, I don't need reverse, for exampe I want change ID with NAME...

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко then replace the .reverse method with the method that would put it in the order you want. An answer to your question doesn't have to have code that you can copy paste.

Comment: @KevinB any other ideas how to change order?

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко this answer demonstrates how to change the order. So does the duplicate question linked at the top.

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко I added a sorting object which should include all keys and their order.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
const sortObj = ({id, name, avatar, ...more}) => ({avatar, name, id, ...more})

const objs = [...]
const objsSorted = objs.map(sortObj)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var sortObj = function sortObj(obj) {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key);
      }
    }
    keys.sort();
    
    let newObj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
      newObj[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    }
    return newObj;
};

let arr = [{id: "58eeed338b115",  name: "Bob", avatar: "" },
{id: "58eeed338b115",  name: "Bob", avatar: "" }];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  console.log(sortObj(arr[i]));
}
```